# Updating Child Nodes and their attributes information - Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to update macaddress information in one of the XML files available on my servers.
I see two types of situations where the

```
<configuration>
  <serverIdentification id="1d230d28-08bc-4a12-a56a-7dacf7f09282" />
  <NetworkBinding ReSync="false" PublicAddress="dev-000450-02a.gsccloud.ninja" PublicPort="">
   <macAddresses />
  </NetworkBinding>
.
.
.
</configuration>
```

or

```
 <configuration>
      <serverIdentification id="1d230d28-08bc-4a12-a56a-7dacf7f09282" />
      <NetworkBinding ReSync="false" PublicAddress="dev-000450-02a.gsccloud.ninja" PublicPort="">
         <macaddresses>

       </macaddresses>
      </NetworkBinding>
    .
    .
    .
    </configuration>
```

The desired XMLData should be the like the one shown below. Please note address(Addr) value is empty.
This will get updated through some other mechanism. So don't worry about it. For now I just want the XML data to look like shown below.

```
<configuration>
          <serverIdentification id="1d230d28-08bc-4a12-a56a-7dacf7f09282" />
          <NetworkBinding ReSync="false" PublicAddress="dev-000450-02a.gsccloud.ninja" PublicPort="">
             <macaddresses>
              <Mac Addr="" />
           </macaddresses>
          </NetworkBinding>
        .
        .
        .
        </configuration>
```

From what I can see is that the child node "macAddresses" is present but the innerxml data is empty.

```
 $xmlfilepath  = "C\somepath\path"
    [xml] $XMLData = Get-Content -LiteralPath $xmlfilepath -ErrorAction Stop
```

[image]

Sorry my knowledge of XML manipulation is not that great. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Read the input file into an XML DOM.
[xml] $xmlData = Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $xmlfilepath -ErrorAction Stop

# Target the <macAddresses> element and add the desired child element
# via its .InnerXml property.
# Note the required use of indexing syntax (['macAddresses']).
$xmlData.configuration.NetworkBinding['macAddresses'].InnerXml = '<Mac Addr="" />'

# $xmlData is now updated; inspect with .OuterXml or save to a file
# with, say, $xmlData.Save("$PWD/new.xml")
```

Note: *Index* notation - `$xmlData.configuration.NetworkBinding['macAddresses']` - rather than *dot notation* - `$xmlData.configuration.NetworkBinding.macAddresses` must be used in order to reliably target the `<macAddresses>` element:

**PowerShell's *dot notation*** (`.macAddresses`) is usually very convenient, but **in the case of *leaf* elements (those that either have *no content at all* or *text* content only, *except* if they have *attributes*), it returns the element's *string content* rather than the *element object itself* ([`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement))**:

- You ***can* use dot notation to modify the *text content* of a leaf element** (e.g., `$xmlData.configuration.NetworkBinding.macAddresses = 'foo'`)
- You ***cannot* use dot notation to *access properties* or *call methods* on leaf elements** (e.g., `$xmlData.configuration.NetworkBinding.macAddresses.InnerXml = '<foo/>'` *fails* - `.macAddresses` is treated as a `[string]`, and a string has no `.InnerXml` property)

  - Note that *non*-leaf elements are *always* returned as themselves (`XmlElement` instances).

By contrast, ***index notation*** (`['macAddresses']`), a type-native feature, allows you **target child elements by name as well, but *consistently* returns them as `XmlElement` objects**, so you can access properties such as `.InnerXml` on them or call methods such as `.SetAttribute()`.

Note, however, that this **index notation by design only ever returns the *first* element of that name** among the children, even if *multiple* ones are present (which PowerShell's dot notation exposes as an *array*); to **target an element *other* than the first one**, **use

`.SelectNodes(<name>)[<n>]` on the element**, where `<n>` is a positional index, as in an array.

In your case, since you want to add a *child* node to the `<macAddresses>` element, via assignment to the `.InnerXml` property, index notation is therefore required.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with a different solution. This is a snippet of my code which I will be using within a function.

```
[xml] $XMLData = Get-Content -LiteralPath $xmlfilepath -ErrorAction Stop

$appSettingsXml = @"
<macAddresses>
    <Mac Addr="" />
</macAddresses> 
"@ 


    if(($XMLData.configuration.NetworkBinding.InnerXml -eq "<macAddresses></macAddresses>") -or ($XMLData.configuration.NetworkBinding.InnerXml -eq "<macAddresses />")){
        $XMLData.configuration.NetworkBinding.InnerXml=""
        $XMLData.configuration.NetworkBinding.InnerXml=$appSettingsXml
    }
.
.
.
.
$XMLData.save($xmlfilepath)
```